# Create Class List for Each Item in Array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a static array of string[] items as below:

```
public string[] stringItems = {"sItem1", "sItem2", "sItem3"}
```

I also have a class list the following.  Each array item will need to have this class list object:

```
public class PriceList
{
    public DateTime listDate { get; set; }
    public decimal listPrice { get; set; 
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("Date: {0}; Price: {1};", listDate, listPrice);
}
```

I set the data using the following:

```
 dataList.Add(new PriceList() { listDate = today, listPrice = price, theVolume = volume });
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to set the data for each index in the array using a for loop?  I think each array item will need to have it's own Prices list class, but I'm not sure how to set and call them.  It might be easiest for me to set it up as a method with parameters and call that for each array item.

Thanks.

> To make my question more clear, I need the following: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AajZf.png)

The properties of each sItem might have 100 or 100,000 list items.  Each sItem will always have the same amount of list items.

At different points in my program, I need to call the sItems directly for other data points.

Comment: Create one more class with two properties first index and second properties return type should be your class "PriceList" and create an array of that class and iterate it then you will get pricelist for every item, hope it will help for you.

Comment: I think you have me headed in the right direction.  Would it look something like: Public Class PopertyData { public int index {get;set;} public PriceList properties{get;set;}} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Item {
   public string Name { get;set;}
   public List<PriceList> Prices {get;set;} = new List<PriceList>();
}

public string[] stringItems = {"sItem1", "sItem2", "sItem3"};
var items=stringItems.Select(x=>new Item {Name=x});

-- Adding --
items.First(i=>i.Name=="sItems1").Prices.Add(new PriceList() { ... });
```

Comment: Can you add an alternate answer not using LINQ?

Comment: Depends on what you are actually going to be doing with the data.  It would be efficient to use a dictionary for quick look ups, but it could be better to use a different data structure depending on how it will be most used.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better to create a class that include the item description:

```
public class PriceList
{
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime listDate { get; set; }
    public decimal listPrice { get; set; }
    public int theVolume { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Item: {0}; Date: {1}; Price: {2}; Volume {3};", itemDescription, listDate, listPrice, theVolume);
    }
}
```

You could dynamically add entries to an `ArrayList` (in `System.Collections`) or a `List<T>`):

```
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
```

or

```
List<PriceList> items = new List<PriceList>();
```

Then you can loop through your static list

```
foreach (string s in stringItems)
{
    PriceList pl = new PriceList () { itemDescription = s, listDate = today, listPrice = price, theVolume = volume };
    items.Add (pl);
}
```

Both `ArrayList` and `List` you can reference directly at indexed positions with items[*n*] and you can also use foreach.

Comment: If all items on the list are of same type,  List<T> should be used. It's a better choise for both type safety and performance.

Comment: Agreed... `List<T>` is so much more useful - with Array being explicitly mentioned in the question I gave an answer using that and an improvement :)

Comment: They are of the same type.  However stringItems[1] will have a class list that might have 10,000 lines to it.  I need to access the list for each item and slice and dice based on any of the variables.  listDate, ListPrice, Volume, etc.